# SailsJS & Waterline - Change models connections dynamically

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm currently working on a project (SailsJS 0.11) with different databases. All my users have different read permissions on those databases. For example :

- I have two databases DB_A and DB_B
- There are two users USER_A and USER_B
- USER_A has only the right to read on DB_A
- USER_B has only the right to read on DB_B

Therefore, I would like to modify my models connection based on the user which is querying them. Is that possible ? How would you do that ?

Thanks for reading and have a nice day !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sails.js - I want to add DB connection dynamically after sails lift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454176/sails-js-i-want-to-add-db-connection-dynamically-after-sails-lift)

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of sails 0.11.x, this is not possible.

You could create a set of models around each connection and change what model your referencing based on each user. You can keep the code DRY, but importing your models definitions from a single place, but have them reference if their on the writeDatabase or the readDatabase. For instance, you could create the `user` model twice. `userWrite.js` & `userRead.js`, each one can import the same model definition with the exception that each references a different db connection.

Comment: I'm currently working on some workaround. I'll post my solution when it's ok :)