# SailsJS - Dynamically change database name

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js, database

In my **connections.js** I have specified one mongodb connection:

```
someMongodbServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    user: '',
    password: '',
    database: 'your_mongo_db_name_here'
  }
```

and in my controller I have overwritten the database name like this:

```
module.exports = {
  sync: function (req, res) {
    var params = req.params.all();
    sails.config.connections.someMongodbServer.database = "newDynamicName";
    console.log(sails.config.connections.someMongodbServer);
    User.create(params, function(err, users) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.status(201);
            res.json(users);
        });

  }

};
```

but it still uses the name specified in **connections.js** (that database is created as soon as the application is lifted)

In case I don't provide any database name in connections.js, by default it will create and use a one named **sails**

I need to create a database in my controller with a dynamic name and insert new rows there after I create them. Any help here?

Comment: Sails generate database when it bootstrap, that's why your code is not working may be trying the same at bootstrap.js @ config folder will help you somehow

Comment: But when the application bootstraps I dont have the name of the database, anyway, what shall I do in that file?

Comment: `sails.config.connections.someMongodbServer.database = "newDynamicName";` copy this code over `bootstrap.js` before the cb()

Comment: It didn't change anything. It works the same way it used to. It will use the database name I specified in connections.js and if I didn't specified any, it will create one called sails. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sails.js - I want to add DB connection dynamically after sails lift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454176/sails-js-i-want-to-add-db-connection-dynamically-after-sails-lift)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the database name is static, meaning it never over written. As you have assigned 'your_mongo_db_name_here' to database variable. There for no matter what you assign to database name before this call, it will never be assigned to the database name.

There for the solution would to be have a constructor parameter or create as function

Comment: And how would I call this constructor and pass the db name to the connection from the controller? I thought that overwriting the global config object would be the solution. I'm new in NodeJS so that's why I'm getting a hard time with this