# How to reload a controller on a function call in sails

Tags: sails.js

I need to set the connection attributes in a controller to set them dynamically. Since I could not set them inside a function in controller I set them globally outside module.exports. But controller does not automatically reload when the data is changed

Here is my controller:

```
sails.config.connections.someMongodbServer.host= sails.services.connectionservice.host

sails.config.connections.someMongodbServer.adapter = sails.services.connectionservice.adapter

sails.config.connections.someMongodbServer.user = sails.services.connectionservice.user

sails.config.connections.someMongodbServer.password = 
sails.services.connectionservice.password

sails.config.connections.someMongodbServer.database = sails.services.connectionservice.database

sails.config.connections.someMongodbServer.port = sails.services.connectionservice.port

module.exports = {

 
  },
```

I'm getting data from a service "connectionservice"

Comment: That is not possible with Waterline, unless you are wiling to make heavy modifications in the source code and the way it loads. However you can use another ORM, like `mongoose` to bind your operations to that connection programatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sails.js - I want to add DB connection dynamically after sails lift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454176/sails-js-i-want-to-add-db-connection-dynamically-after-sails-lift)