# Dynamic database connection after lift using sails js version 1

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

i want solution for MYsql only

I want to switch database on per request bases 
i have achieved it in previous versions of sails but with this new version (1.0.0)
i am not able to do
[sails.js - I want to add DB connection dynamically after sails lift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454176/sails-js-i-want-to-add-db-connection-dynamically-after-sails-lift/49317965#49317965)

there is no documentation for it

i have primary database lets say DB_A which i use as default datastore to authenticate users after it users have their own database to interact 
and after lift it can be any database present in system with which user can connect and fetch

a few option i discovered

1) reload orm

2) create-manager

but dont know how to work with it as none of them are suggested

can any one help me with it

Comment: have you found any solution to it?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the similar issue while I was using PostgreSQL in sails app. I 
    found a workaround below.
    i.e. npm install pg.
     in your case install mysql plugin i.e. npm i mysql

I have created dbconnections.js in the sails app controllers folder

```
const a = {
  host: 'abc.com',
  port: 'xxxx',
  database: 'xxxx',
  user: 'xxxx',
  password: 'xxxx'
}

const b = {
  host: 'ecd.com',
 port: 'xxxx',
  database: 'xxxx',
  user: 'xxxx',
  password: 'xxxx'
}


module.exports = { a: a, b: b};
```

then in my other controllers I have used pg plugin to match with the user passed db 
     env through api

i.e in my other controller

```
var sourceFile = require('./dbconnections.js');

const {
      Client
    } = require('pg');
```

for your case you could follow this https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql to 
     create connection object and follow the below logic to dynamically connect 
     to different dbs

```
    var match_env;

    for (x in sourceFile) {

      if (x === env) {
        match_env = sourceFile[x];

      }
    }

    const client = new Client(match_env)
```

now client object will have all postgresql transactions which one could 
      execute, i.e.
        client.connect()
        const qry = "select * from person where city= "newyork";
        client.query(qry, function (err, resp) {

```
    console.log("before", client)

    client.end();
    console.log("after", client)
    //user = JSON.parse(user);
    if (err) {
      return res.json({
        error: err
      });
    }
    if (resp === undefined) {
      return res.notFound();
    } else
      console.log(resp);
    return res.json({
      userData: resp.rows
    });

  }

);
```

Based on the use case we could move the above code to other js file and call 
    in as 
    many controller as we can and this would work with multiple for multiple db 
    connections of postgres sql in sails app.

Comment: Actually i solved it at that time i was using sails@0.12 so proper way was to use node-mysql driver and create own orm only for mysql

But i your case it can be implemented by Datastore
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores

Comment: True, i solved it the same way you did. I wish you would have posted the solution. Thanks